# Raspberry pi oled display

Tags: python, arduino, electronics

I have got a problem with Raspberry Pi and Oled display (128x32). Yesterday I tried and everything was OK, but today when I started working it didn't work. Raspberry Pi detecting i2c device. I'm using python for it. Also I've tried connect it to Arduino but there too didn't work, but i2c address found.

Comment: Please check your question and ask yourself: what have another reader to know what you know, to understand the question. The only thing I understand is, that your oled isn't working.